# Python win32 read/modify/store/map Name Box

Tags: python, excel, xlsx, xlrd, win32com

I'm trying to do some work on a complex Excel Workbook which has a large number of variables which have been created and used using the Name Box feature. See picture attached for example/detail.
I'd like to store or change DeathRate or maybe read all the Name Boxes and create a dictionary between names and locations of the cell from outside Excel.
I'm using the win32com library in Python but I guess I could switch to another Excel reader as long as it copes with XLSX files.
Has someone come across this before?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution, see code below:

```
import os
from win32com.client import Dispatch #win32com is based around cells beginning at one.
app_xl = Dispatch("Excel.Application")
WORKING_DIR = os.getcwd()
excelPath = WORKING_DIR + "\SampleModel.xls"

wb = app_xl.Workbooks.Open(excelPath)

# Get Named Boxes
name_box_list = [x for x in app_xl.ActiveWorkbook.Names]
name_box_map = {x.Name:x.Value for x in name_box_list}

print name_box_list
print name_box_map

# Change Named Boxes
name_box_list[0].Name = u'NewName'
name_box_list[0].Value = u'=model!$B$5'
name_box_map = {x.Name:x.Value for x in name_box_list}
```